A data structure for range minimum queries
Here is a data structure question in the comparison model that I can't answer.
I have an array $A$ of $n$ elements. I work in the comparison model, meaning that the elements can only be compared with each other. I would like to create a data structure supporting the following two operations.
$\mathrm{Decrease}(i, x)$: change the value of $A[i]$ to $\min\{A[i], x\}$.
$\mathrm{Minimum(i, j)}$: return the minimum in the interval $A[i:j]$.
Is it possible to implement the first operation in time $\mathrm O(1)$ and the second operation in time $|j-i|^{0.99}$? For example, segment trees can answer both questions in $O(\log n)$, but I want the first operation to be extremely fast.

With SQRT decomposition you can decrease the value of an element in constant time, and update the block of the element in constant time as well.
Query time is $O(\sqrt n)$.

For more information, chunk the data into blocks of size $\sqrt n$ and for each block, store the minimum value of its elements. Now, if you want to decrease an item, update its block to the minimum of its current value and the new value.
For the query, if the query happens inside a block, you run it in $\sqrt n$ time, by simply looking at all values in the block. Otherwise you look at all the values of the blocks between the two indices in time $\sqrt n + \sqrt n + \sqrt n = O(\sqrt n)$.

Thanks! However, this does not answer the question, since it is too slow for short intervals: I want to answer them in time proportional to $\ell^{0.99}$, not $\sqrt{n}$.

I agree that this doesn't satisfy that criterion when $\ell =O(\sqrt n)$, but since you're example used $\log n$ as an acceptable query time, I assumed sublinear was acceptable.
